# How to extract data from views in db schema into a dataframe in glue

Tags: aws-glue

I would like to create and extract from a view in a postgres database.

I can do that via creating a spark context and extracting information in the glue script however I loose the data cataloging feature. Is there any way to work from the data catalog/crawlers and then access this in the glue script.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Glue `create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog()` API and Crawler work on tables only. You will have to use `sparkcontext` to fetch data using query over view.

```
spark.read.format("jdbc")
.option("url", jdbcUrl)
.option("query", "select c1, c2 from t1")
.load() to fetch data using query
```